# Changing the color of selected items in react-select

Tags: react-select

I want to change the color of the selected items in react select. Currently the selected items appear blue. I want to change the color to grey

[image]

Towards this I did the following steps

1. created a file called MyComponent.scss

   ```
   $grey: #999;
   .Select--multi {
   .Select-value {
       background-color: $grey;
       color: $grey;
   }}
   ```

and then imported this file into my component

```
import 'react-select/scss/default.scss';
import './MyComponent.scss';
```

My hope was that this will override the default color with my $grey variable.

But the color is still blue.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the color of this requires some juggling of .css as there are a lot of elements that have to be changed.  Remember that the 4th number of rgba represents translucence.  Here are the elements that need to be changed:

```
div.Select-control>.Select-value { 
background-color: rgba(153, 153, 153, .08);
border: 1px solid rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.24);
color: #999;
}
div.Select-control>.Select-value>.Select-value-icon {
border-right: 1px solid rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.24);
}
div.Select-control>.Select-value>.Select-value-label, .Select-value>a {
color: #999;
}
```

Towards changing these elements, I recommend using selectors like I've demonstrated, however you can also override colors using !important just after the notation.  Generally, the most specific style wins if it all exists at the same level in .css.

Two great tools exist to do this... First in Chrome right click the element and look at your inspector (styles).  Second, an rgba calculator is available at http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/.

PS... I noticed that you've got one declaration inside the curlies of another; generally if I want to do multiple selections I use .Select--multi, .Select-value { not one value inside another's brackets with .css or I use the > for child elements.